# How to parse array-like JSONObject (Android)?

Tags: android, json

#### Problem

I have a returned `JSONObject` instance `aJsonObjectInstance` from a API is like this (in human readable form):

```
[
    {
        "key_11":"value_11",
        "key_12":"value_12",
        "key_13":"value_13"
    },

    {
        "key_21":"value_21",
        "key_22":"value_22",
        "key_23":"value_23"
    },

    {
        "key_31":"value_31",
        "key_32":"value_32",
        "key_33":"value_33"
    }
]
```

Looks like it is a `JSONArray` instance, but the class is truly `JSONObject`, how can I parse it into an array of `JSONObject`?

Comment: Parse it as you are parsing JsonArray

Comment: Oh, that simple! Let me have a try :D

Comment: No, it doesn't work: when I type `String value = aJsonObjectInstance.getJSONObject(0).getString("key_11");`, there is a compile-time error asking me to change into `String value = aJsonObjectInstance.optJSONObject(0).getString("key_11");`. And when I make that change, there is another compile-time error asking to change into `String value = aJsonObjectInstance.getJSONObject(0).getString("key_11");`. Should the JSONObject be casted into JSONArray first?

Comment: Simply create a `JSONArray` from the object you have..`JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(aJsonObjectInstance.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gson library if it always looks like this.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<MyModel>(){}.getType();
MyModel model = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```